# Why AngularJS Counter still works w/o init?

Tags: angularjs

There is a simple example of counter using ngClick in the official doc.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

My question is why it still works when I remove `ng-init="count=0"`. I thought that `count` should be `undefined`, what kind of magic does AngularJS perform behind the scene?

Comment: It is `undefined` that is why there is no zero when you remove the `ng-init`. When you click increment it will notice that `count` doesn't exist and assign it.

Comment: That I noticed, the thing is `undefined` + 1 is `NaN`, it is as if AngularJS auto-init `count` to 0? I mean, when you start clicking, the count will be incremented correctly.

Comment: AngularJS notices that the variable is `undefined` so it creates it and sets it to `null`, once you increment it by one it pretty much realizes it is a number and it is now a set variable. So it never actually does `undefined + 1`, it does `null + 1`

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting to know, is this behavior documented somewhere in AngularJS documentation?